# Filtering Linq based on Enum, with a specific unique value exception

Tags: c#, linq, enums

In order to simplify, let say I have `MyEnum` and `MyClass`:

```
enum MyEnum
{
    Undefined = 0,
    A = 1,
    B = 2,
    C = 3,
    D = 4
}

class MyClass { MyEnum MyEnumValue { get; set; } }
```

In order to filter a list of `MyClass` by a `MyEnum` value I'm using:

```
list.Where(r => r.MyEnumValue == myEnum);
```

But if the `MyEnum` is equal to specific value (lets say `MyEnum.B`) I would need the list to return **also** any values that equal to `MyEnum.B` or `MyEnum.A`.

This is what I've came up with:

```
public static MyClass MyClass_By_MyEnum(IEnumarable<MyClass> list, MyEnum myEnum)
{
    if (myEnum == MyEnum.B)
    {
        return list.Where(r =>
                        r.MyEnumValue == MyEnum.A || 
                        r.MyEnumValue == MyEnum.B ||
                        r.MyEnumValue == MyEnum.C
                    ).FirstOrDefault();
    }
    else
    {
        return list.Where(r => r.MyEnumValue == myEnum).FirstOrDefault();
    }
}
```

Is there any way achieving this using one line only? without the if else statement?

EDIT 1:
I'm searching for a better design based solution, any suggestion?

Comment: could you not just cast to int and use a `>=` or `<=` operator?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use an array. Also, you don't need to use `Where` since you can pass the delegate to `FirstOrDefault`.

```
var lookFor = new [] { MyEnum.A, MyEnum.B, MyEnum.C };
return list.FirstOrDefault(r => lookFor.Contains(r.MyEnumValue));
```

Comment: why not `!=`, it will reduce linq query as well as easy to read

Answer (score 2):

This is the shortest I can think of. Not sure if that makes the intent much clearer however.

```
list.Where(r => r.MyEnumValue == myEnum || (myEnum == MyEnum.B && r.MyEnumValue == MyEnum.A)).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: Hey @Botz, thanks, but in my taste it is still not clearer to maintain than the simple If else statement. See the updated question, I've also added C to compare with. I'm search for a design based solution.

Comment: why not `!=`, it will reduce linq query as well as easy to read

Answer (score 1):

what about `!=`

```
 return list.Where(r =>
                        r.MyEnumValue != MyEnum.Undefined  || 
                        r.MyEnumValue != MyEnum.D
                    ).FirstOrDefault();
```

In real case we can take less elements in `lookFor` array and use negation, something like

```
var lookFor = new [] { MyEnum.Undefined, MyEnum.D};
return list.FirstOrDefault(r => !lookFor.Contains(r.MyEnumValue));
```

Please check negation in FirstOrDefault query, this will help us to reduce elements in `loofFor` array

Comment: Good answer, but for me working with `!=` is less intuitive to understand but still upvoted.

Comment: Agreed.. happy coding

Answer (score 0):

Ended up mixing @john-wu and @botz3000 answers with:

```
var lookFor = new [] { MyEnum.A, MyEnum.B, MyEnum.C };

list.FirstOrDefault(r => r.MyEnumValue == myEnum || (
                             myEnum == MyEnum.B && lookFor.Contains(r.MyEnumValue)
                         )
                    );
```

Comment: why not `!=`, it will reduce linq query as well as easy to read

Comment: Its true in the case of the simplified question, but in the real code there are many enum options

Comment: I updated my answer as you mentioned in above comments